# When downloaded CSV file with Arabic characters is displayed as symbols

Tags: html, character-encoding

I am using this HTML code to download YT Comments

It is from here:
https://github.com/charitha213/youtube-comments-downloader/blob/main/comment_downloader.html

The downloaded CSV has non-Arabic characters like this:

```
Ø³ÙˆÙ‘ÙŠØªÙ‡Ø§ ÙˆØ¨ØµØ±Ø§Ø­Ù‡ ØªØ¬Ù†Ù† ØªØ¬Ù†Ù† Ø§Ù„Ù„Ù‡ ÙŠØ¹Ø·ÙŠÙƒ Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø§ÙÙŠÙ‡
```

I searched and tried to add encoding in this portion of the HTML code but nothing worked

```
            var blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv' });

            // Create a download link for the CSV file
            var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            downloadLink.download = 'comments.csv';
            downloadLink.innerHTML = '<button>Download CSV</button>';

            // Append the download link to the result container
            var resultContainer = document.getElementById('result');
            resultContainer.appendChild(downloadLink);
```

How Can I make the downloaded CSV file display correct Arabic characters

Thanks for your help

I searched and tried to add encoding in the HTML like this

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="encoding-indexes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="encoding.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="FileSaver.js"></script>
</head>
```

But it had no effect

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Ø³ÙˆÙ‘ÙŠØªÙ‡Ø§ ÙˆØ¨ØµØ±Ø§Ø­Ù‡'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'utf-8')` returns `'سوّيتها وبصراحه'` and vice versa: `'سوّيتها وبصراحه'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` -> `'Ø³ÙˆÙ‘ÙŠØªÙ‡Ø§ ÙˆØ¨ØµØ±Ø§Ø\xadÙ‡'`. FYI, `\xad` is `­` (U+00AD,  *Soft Hyphen*)

Comment: Thank you, is there an HTML code I can add to make the downloaded CSV display correct Arabic letters?